# LARAVEL: Setting up a route to a method called assign on a controller?

Tags: laravel, routes

I have the following route that does not want to work:

```
Route::get ('address/{id}/assign', array('uses' => 'AddressesController@assign'));
```

I have the following method in AddressesController.php:

```
public function assign() {
    print 'HELLO'; die();
}
```

I am trying to access:

```
http://localhost/address/1/assign
```

But it is NOT hitting the assign function. I keep getting:

```
Method [assign] does not exist.
```

Any ideas why?

**UPDATE**

I've tried all these variations:

```
public function assign($id)
{
    print 'XXX'; die();
}

public function getAssign($id)
{
    print 'XXX'; die();
}

public function postAssign($id)
{
    print 'XXX'; die();
}

public function assignAction($id)
{
    print 'XXX'; die();
}

public function actionAssign($id)
{
    print 'XXX'; die();
}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I had another controller with the same class name. That is why it was causing issues. Be careful when you copy and paste folks. Someone please delete or close this...

Comment: what's your base url to the directory? it surely seems like there is different controller acting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a parameter in you function declaration since you use one in your route ( {id} ).

Like this:

```
public function assign($id) {
    print 'HELLO'; die($id);
}
```